# Speed Up Execution ,Python

Tags: python, performance, for-loop, spell-checking

`for` loops are quite expensive when it comes to execution time. I am building a correction algorithm and I've used peter norvig's code of spell correction . I modified it a bit and realized it is taking too long to execute the optimization on thousands of words.

The algorithm checks for 1 and 2 edit distance and corrects it. I've made it 3 . So that might increase the time (I am not sure).  Here is a part of the end where the highest occurring words are used as reference:

```
def correct(word):
    candidates = (known([word]).union(known(edits1(word)))).union(known_edits2(word).union(known_edits3(word)) or [word]) # this is where the problem is

    candidate_new = []
    for candidate in candidates: #this statement isnt the problem
        if soundex(candidate) == soundex(word):
            candidate_new.append(candidate)
    return max(candidate_new, key=(NWORDS.get))
```

And it looks like the statement `for candidate in candidates` is increasing the execution time. You could easily have a look at the code of peter norvig, Click [here](http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html).
I've figured out the problem. It's in the statement

```
candidates = (known([word]).union(known(edits1(word)))
             ).union(known_edits2(word).union(known_edits3(word)) or [word])
```

where ,

```
def known_edits3(word):
    return set(e3 for e1 in edits1(word) for e2 in edits1(e1) 
                                      for e3 in edits1(e2) if e3 in NWORDS)
```

It can be seen that there are 3 for loops inside `edits3` which increases execution time 3 fold. `edits2` has 2 for loops . so this is the culprit.

How do I minimize this expression? 
Could `itertools.repeat` help out with this one??

Comment: Increase execution time *compared to what*?

Comment: Try a list comprehension first, and see if that improves things: `candidate_new = [candidate for candidate in candidates if soundex(candidate) == soundex(word)]`

Comment: @Evert I'm curious, but why would a list comprehension have any measurable impact?

Comment: @HannesOvrén, Onc reason: list comprehension would not call the `append` method in each iteration.

Comment: Had to actually try it, and yes, it seems like this is the case. Thanks! Did not know this actually mattered at all.

Comment: check my question again. The problem is something else. i have edited it.

Comment: I'd suggest running a profile on this with a focus on the `known_edits`.  You need to find out whether it is the iteration mechanism that is taking up time, or the many calls to `edits1`.

Comment: could i use nose-timer here?? or any other way to find out the timing for each function inside the for loop?

Answer (score 2):

A couple of ways to increase performance here:

1. Use list comprehension (or generator)
2. Don't compute the same thing in each iteration

The code would reduce to:

```
def correct(word):
    candidates = (known([word]).union(known(edits1(word)))).union(known_edits2(word).union(known_edits3(word)) or [word])

    # Compute soundex outside the loop
    soundex_word = soundex(word)

    # List compre
    candidate_new = [candidate for candidate in candidates if soundex(candidate) == soundex_word]

    # Or Generator. This will save memory
    candidate_new = (candidate for candidate in candidates if soundex(candidate) == soundex_word)

    return max(candidate_new, key=(NWORDS.get))
```

Another enhancement is based on the fact that you need only the MAX candidate

```
def correct(word):
    candidates = (known([word]).union(known(edits1(word)))).union(known_edits2(word).union(known_edits3(word)) or [word])

    soundex_word = soundex(word)
    max_candidate = None
    max_nword = 0
    for candidate in candidates:
        if soundex(candidate) == soundex_word and NWORDS.get(candidate) > max_nword:
            max_candidate = candidate
    return max_candidate
```

Comment: hi , thanks . but when i looked closely , i realized the problem is something else. check my question , i have edited it.