# checking the execution time for sub-instructions, python

Tags: python, performance, function, for-loop, timeit

How should i check the execution time for a sub instruction in python? The execution time for any instruction is easily available by adding  %time before calling the function:

```
%time function call
```

now i have to know what really consumes time in a 3 level for loop (it is obvious that 3 for loops within each other will increase the time 3 fold). here's the code:

```
candidates = (known([word]).union(known(edits1(word)))).union(known_edits2(word).union(known_edits3(word)) or [word])
```

where,

```
def known_edits2(word):
    return set(e2 for e1 in edits1(word) for e2 in edits1(e1) if e2 in NWORDS)
def known_edits3(word):
    return set(e3 for e1 in edits1(word) for e2 in edits1(e1) for e3 in edits1(e2) if e3 in NWORDS)
```

I need to find out whether the iteration is taking more time or the multiple calls to edits1. So i need to find the time for each bit. i looked up and found about timeit function , but being a beginner i do not know how to put it to use.

Comment: try `cProfile` package

Comment: *"it is obvious that 3 for loops within each other will increase the time 3 fold"*. No, they won't. You need to multiply -- rather than add  -- them together.

Comment: could you show me that practically @fourtheye . npe : yes ,that is what 3 fold means, i guess..

Comment: @Sword: You can see examples here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html

Comment: Anyway it is in O(N^3). One small optimization would be, make `NWORDS` a set.

Comment: i have another thread on the speed optimization here[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21780334/speed-up-execution-python] . could you provide a solution to that question @thefourtheye